# EventEmitter is not trigger properly from ng-container & ng-template collapsible Tree | Angular 13

Tags: javascript, angular, eventemitter, viewchild, collapsibletree-r

**I have the below structure:**

```
app-component --> based on the value received do-something
    - side-resultview.component --> Emits a value to app-component
         - collapsible-tree.component --> Emits a value to side-resultview.component
```

Where I am trying to display a collapsible tree based on some JSON returned from a service.
I have another requirement to do something based which node/sub-node is clicked by user, so I am emitting a value (ID key) to the parent and that is again emitted by to the parent of it as shown in the above structure.

**Issue:**
This is working fine only on the **first level node** i.e. only while clicking on *Column Name 1, Column Name 2, Column Name 3, Column Name 4* and Column Name 5 but **not the child-nodes** in the tree. See the JSON below:

```
{
    "results": [
    {
        "id": "1001",
        "title": "Column Name 1",
        "child": {
            "results": [
            {
                "id": "10001",
                "title": "Column Name 10",
                "child": {
                    "results": [],
                    "size": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "10002",
                "title": "Column Name 11",
                "child": {
                    "results": [
                        {
                            "id": "100011",
                            "title": "Column Name 101",
                            "child": {
                                "results": [],
                                "size": 0
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "100022",
                            "title": "Column Name 111",
                            "child": {
                                "results": [],
                                "size": 0
                            }
                        }],
                    "size": 2
                }
            }],
            "size": 2
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "1002",
        "title": "Column Name 2",
        "child": {
            "results": [],
            "size": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "1003",
        "title": "Column Name 3",
        "child": {
            "results": [],
            "size": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "1004",
        "title": "Column Name 4",
        "child": {
            "results": [
                {
                    "id": "100041",
                    "title": "Column Name 401",
                    "child": {
                        "results": [
                            {
                                "id": "1000041",
                                "title": "Column Name 4011",
                                "child": {
                                    "results": [],
                                    "size": 0
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "1000042",
                                "title": "Column Name 4111",
                                "child": {
                                    "results": [],
                                    "size": 0
                                }
                            }],
                        "size": 2
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": "100042",
                    "title": "Column Name 411",
                    "child": {
                        "results": [],
                        "size": 0
                    }
                }],
            "size": 2
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "1005",
        "title": "Column Name 5",
        "child": {
            "results": [],
            "size": 0
        }
    }],
    "size": 5
}
```

Detailed code is as below:

**The collapsible-tree.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: '[recursive]',
  templateUrl: './collapsible-tree.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./collapsible-tree.component.css']
})
export class CollapsibleTreeComponent {
  self = this;

  @Output() 
  public nodeTokenValue = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor() { }

  @Input() level: number | undefined;
  @Input() children: any;
  @Input() parent: any;
  @Input() search: (() => Observable<any>) | undefined;

  expandNode(_item: { isOpen: boolean; }): void {    
    _item.isOpen = !_item.isOpen;
  }
  
  public nodeItemNameClicked(_item: any): void {
    this.nodeTokenValue.emit(_item.id);  // Emitting the ID key of the node 
  }
}
```

**The collapsible-tree.component.html**

```
<ul class="tree" *ngIf="level==undefined">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tree;context:{children:children,search:search}">
    </ng-container>
</ul>
<ng-container *ngIf="level!=undefined">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tree;context:{children:children,search:search}">
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #tree let-children="children" let-search="search">
    <li *ngFor="let item of children">
        <span [ngClass]="item.child.size>0?'plus-node':'close-node'">
            <a (click)="item.child.size>0 && expandNode(item)">
                <i [ngClass]="item.child.size>0?'bi bi-plus-square-fill':'bi bi-dash-square'"></i>               
            </a>

            <!-- This is a click event applied on the nodes -->
            <a (click)="nodeItemNameClicked(item)">&nbsp;&nbsp;{{item.title}}</a>
        </span>    
        <ul recursive *ngIf="item.child.size>0 && item.isOpen"
            [children]="item.child.results" 
            [parent]="self" 
            [level]="level!=undefined?level+1:0"
            [search]="search">
        </ul>
    </li>
</ng-template>
```

**Which generates a Collapsible Tree as below:**

[image: sample tree]

**The side-resultview.component.html:**

```
<div recursive [children]="searchResultJson" 
    [search]="commonSettingsService.getElasticResult" 
    (nodeTokenValue)="getNodeTokenValue($event)">
</div>
```

**The side-resultview.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonSettingsService } from '/services/common-settings.service';
import { CollapsibleTreeComponent } from '/collapsible-tree/collapsible-tree.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'treeview-result',
  templateUrl: './side-resultview.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./side-resultview.component.css']
})
export class SideResultviewComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() 
  public getNodeTokenValueFromTree = new EventEmitter<any>();

  @ViewChild(CollapsibleTreeComponent, { static: false })

  nodeTokenValue = 0;
  searchResultJson: any[];

  constructor(public commonSettingsService: CommonSettingsService) {
    this.searchResultJson = [];
  }

  ngOnInit(): void { 
    this.commonSettingsService.getElasticResult().subscribe(data => {
      this.searchResultJson = data.results;
    });
  }

  public getNodeTokenValue($event: any): void {
    this.nodeTokenValue = $event;
    this.getNodeTokenValueFromTree.emit(this.nodeTokenValue);
  }
}
```

**In app-component.html:**

```
<div id="grouping" class="tab-pane fade active">
   <treeview-result (getNodeTokenValueFromTree)="checkNodeItemId($event)"></treeview-result>
</div>
```

**In app-component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { SideResultviewComponent } from '/side-resultview/side-resultview.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-compoment',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(SideResultviewComponent, { static: false })
  tabIndex: any;
  
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() { }  

  checkNodeItemId($event: any) {
    this.tabIndex = parseInt($event);
    console.log(this.tabIndex);     // Giving console out for first-level Node only not the next level.
  } 
}
```

Comment: It's looks like this another [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71949405/how-to-get-array-object-from-angular-custom-infinity-tree-view-when-i-am-clickin/71950120#71950120), sorry, I'm in hurry and I can not checked